# How do i save the data from a MongoDB into my php file as an array and then do a redirect?

Tags: php, html, arrays, mongodb, php-mongodb

Aight so basically I'm working on a News site as a project and in the homepage (index.php) i need to show the articles on the main page that are saved in a document on the mongodb database for showing it basically i have this function

```php
    $ARR_articles = article_recordset();
    
    $STR_article = NULL;
    
    foreach($ARR_articles as $index => $article){
        $STR_article .= get_article_item_html(
            $img_path = "img/article/".$index.".jpg", 
            $title = $article["title"], 
            $description = $article["content"]
        );
    }
```

while the article recordset function is from another functions file which first had various arrays as recordset for the articles while now it's like this

```php
function article_recordset(){
   

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");

$SiteArticles = $client->SiteArticles;
$articoli=$SiteArticles->Articles;
$cursor = $articoli->find();

    foreach ($cursor as $articolo) {
        $recordset = array(
                "title" => $articolo["title"],
                "description" => $articolo["content"],
                "article" => "",
        );

    }
}
```

i try to save the mongodb data as an array so i can show it on the main index using it as an array for the foreach function but it gives me this error: "Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in *File path and line*" and idk how to fix it and also how can i also link the echoed articles to other PhP files that are basically the article pages?

Edit: I managed to solve the problem by litteraly adding `return $cursor;` after the find and adding a $i variable for the immages so the article recordset rn is as it follows

```php
function article_recordset(){
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$i = 0;
$SiteArticles = $client->SiteArticles;
$articoli=$SiteArticles->Articles;
$cursor = $articoli->find();
return $cursor;

    foreach ($cursor as $articolo) {      
        $recordset = array(
            $i=$i+1 => array(
                "title" => $articolo["title"],
                "description" => $articolo["content"],
                "article" => "",
            )
        );
    }

}
```

The lil change made the difference then for the immage system too later where i have an img folder with every img named with numbers from 0 to N

Comment: What is the object type and value of `$cursor`?

Comment: Rn i saved it as a normal variable since the find part was from a tutorial i've found online and tried to apply to my code since this is my first time working with PHP and MongoDB together

Comment: Your comment does not answer my question.

Comment: i didn't use $cursor as an object i used it as a variable and the value is the documents of the DB SiteArticles in the collection Articles. The idea as said was to basically do the query of the documents and then treat part of the data like an array i would then display

Comment: I was giving you a hint on what to look for. The value of `$cursor` is null which means the statement that initialized that variable failed.

Comment: the thing is i want `$cursor` to basically have the data of the documents in the mongoDB database (Doc id, title, content, Date, Etc etc) and i thought that throught a foreach it would go throught the database docs and i would later save those data in some arrays the problem is that rn i have no idea on how to do that since the foreach didn't seem to work